# center symbol on origin

Tags: svg, css-animations

I want to center a symbol on the origin 0,0 so that I can rotate it.

This worked in [my example](https://jsr-hersbruck.de/apps/SVG-symbol.html), but the validator marked my x- and y-Attributes as "not allowed".

```
<svg viewBox="-100 -100 600 300">
<defs>
    <symbol id="wheel" x="-10" y="-10" height="20" width="20" viewBox="-10 -10 20 20" >
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="8" />
        <path id="valve" d="m0,-6 v2" />
    </symbol>

</defs>

<use href="#wheel" x="0" y="0" height="20" width="20" />
```

If I move it with a transform: translate(), the rotation won't turn on the spot.

```
    #wheel {
  stroke-width: 4;
  animation: turn .5s infinite linear;
}

#wheel path {
    fill: none;
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 1;
}

@keyframes turn {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Have you any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: stop using the validator perhaps?

Comment: Thx a lot - I'm a German, we just never doubt the powers that be! :-) According to [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/symbol(MDN) x-attribute is ok!